# Logical AND (&&) and OR (||) operators confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logical-operators

I'm still  getting confused with the logical operator. My case is that I'm using React.js component such as below:

```js
const Component = () => {
   const [data, setData] = useState({
      date: "",
      value: "",
   })

   const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data.date !== "" && data.value !== "") {
      setDisabled(false);
    } else if (data.date === "" || data.value === "") {
      setDisabled(true);
    }
  }, [data.date, data.value]);

  return <Button disabled={disabled} />
}
```

So my case here is that I have a state consisting of `date` and `value` where I receive an input from a user. If the input for one of the state (`date` or `value`) is empty, I want the button to be disabled. From my understanding, the logical operator should be correct. What happens right now is that the `Button` will be enabled once both input has been filled. However, if I emptied one of the field, it doesn't get disabled. Only when I empty both input field then `Button` would get disabled. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you so much in advance

**UPDATE**
How I'm changing the state is by:

```js
const handleDate = (_, dateString) => {
   setData({...data, date: dateString});
}

<DatePicker onChange={handleDate} />
<InputNumber onChange={(value) => {setData({...data, value: value})} />
```

*Note: I'm using Ant Design Input and Datepicker

Comment: Where/how are you changing the state? There's nothing in your code that updates data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set if not having date or not having value.

```
setDisabled(!data.date || !data.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
else if
```

use

```
useEffect(() => {
if (data.date !== "" && data.value !== "") {
  setDisabled(false);
} else {
  setDisabled(true);
}
```

}, [data.date, data.value]);

I assume you are using useState correctly whilek changing date and value.
Do keep us updated ;-)

Comment: Instead of using `false` if a boolean expression is `true` and `true` if the same boolean expression is false, you can substitute with the boolean expression and negate it. So `if (expr) { return false; } else { return true; }` becomes `return !exp`. Since the expression here is an AND, we can use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) `!a && !b == !(a || b)` to convert the expression. Double negation cancels out, so the final result is `setDisabled(date.date === "" || date.value === "")`

Answer (score 0):

Or means at least one of them.
AND means both simultaneously.

So your OR (data.date === "" || data.value === "") means when at least one of them is empty it is true; therefore disabled.
And your AND (data.date !== "" && data.value !== "") means if both of them are non empty simultaneously then true, in every other case false.

Comment: The thing is, with the code I have above, it only gets disabled when both are empty.